# Add stipe stripe subscriptions for different projects of each user

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, supabase

The use case I am working on which is common but I need some suggestions to visualize it.
Each user can have multiple projects to which they can subscribe to.

So for example, the User has two projects in his name, Project X and Project Y. Now each has its own subscriptions.

For each project-specific payment how can I tag the customer -> project -> subscription?

I am able to tag customers with subscriptions but not sure how to go about tagging the subscription to a project.

I was thinking something like

1. On user create, adding a customer.
2. On project create add a product with prices.
3. The checkout
4. Session
5. Subscriptions/ checkout completed
6. update DB

Problem with this one I see, if I change the price plans, I will have to update in all the places. :(

What are the best/other alternatives to achieve this?
I am using Nextjs with Supabase for this. Following this example.
https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments

Comment: I have been created smilar app. Could you be more specific `if I change the price plans, I will have to update in all the places`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. So for example https://supabase.io/pricing they have per project / per user or team billing. Also have pay-as-you-go. I have the exact same thing. Now the way I was thinking to do like I commented above, I am thinking if I had to change the pricing let's say 25$ to 30$, I have to go change the price for each project(which are products the was I have described above). Probably not able to visulise how this is gonna work I guess.

Comment: My understanding is, you create mulitple subscription plans first, then users can subscribe one of the plans per project, and users can create multiple projects, right? And  I'm confusing `if I had to change the pricing`. This means you update stripe prices? Stripe prices can not update amount by api. You have to create new stripe price instead and can be referenced from product by using lookup_key and transfer_lookup_key.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you can achieve that by single product and mliti prices pattern with using price.lookup_key so you can reference latest pice of project from stripe product. Of course, in order to update the billing amount for users who have already subscribed, you need to notify them and change their stripe prices programmatically

Comment: `if I had to change the pricing`, yes I meant updating. It does make sense what you said.

Comment: Let's say I don't need to update the pricing. In that case if you had to do something like https://supabase.io/pricing these pricing model how would you go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should create a single `product` and some `prices` for your subscription plans. The `price` represents the entity of your subscription plan.

A `lookup_key` is used to retrieve prices dynamically from a static string and if `transfer_lookup_key` is set to true, will atomically remove the lookup key from the existing price, and assign it to this price. So you can always retrieve a newest price of the plan by using `lookup_key` and set `transfer_lookup_key` true.

```js
const product = await stripe.products.create({
  name: 'MyService', // your service name
});

const beginnerPrice = await stripe.prices.create({
  unit_amount: 5,
  currency: 'usd',
  recurring: {interval: 'month'},
  product: product.id,
  lookup_key: 'beginner',
  transfer_lookup_key: true,
});

const proPrice = await stripe.prices.create({
  unit_amount: 20,
  currency: 'usd',
  recurring: {interval: 'month'},
  product: product.id,
  lookup_key: 'pro',
  transfer_lookup_key: true,
});
```

And here is the db schema I assumed to.

```js
// db schema

interface IUser{
  id: string
  stripeCustomerId: string
}

interface IProject{
  id: string
  userId: string
}

interface IProjectSubscription{
  id: string
  projectId: string
  stripeSubscriptionId: string // or/and stripeCheckoutSessionId, it's up to your use case
}
```

When a user create new project and select his/her subscription plan, you will create new  `checkout.session` and pass corresponding line item with `price`. You can get current `price` of selected plan by using `lookup_key`.

```js
const prices = await stripe.prices.list({
  lookup_keys: ['pro'],
  type: 'recurring',
  limit: 1,
});

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [
    {price: prices[0].id, quantity: 1},
  ],
  mode: 'subscription',
});
```

Then on `checkout.session.completed`, you can receive `checkout.session` object and migrate your db in webhook.

Next, let's say you want to change the price of 'pro' plan 20$ to 30$. In that case, you will create new `price` with same `lookup_key`. By doing so, you can change the subscription price for new subscribers without changing the amount charged to existing subscribers.

```js
const newProPrice = await stripe.prices.create({
  unit_amount: 30,
  currency: 'usd',
  recurring: {interval: 'month'},
  product: product.id,
  lookup_key: 'pro',
  transfer_lookup_key: true,
});
```

Comment: This is brilliant ❤️ But I don't see where you are linking the subscriptionId with project Id for IProjectSubscription?

Comment: @SubhenduKundu When you create the `checkout.session` object, set the projectId in the metadata. The `checkout.session` object with the metadata can be retrieved in the `checkout.session.completed` event of the webhook, and the object now has the stripe subscription id.  https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: I had everything right, just metadata is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) to 'tag' the things in Stripe to map to things in your data model.

If you want to change prices, yes, you'd have to update all the Subscriptions.  Instead you might want to look at either using quantities or metered billing. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/model

Comment: You were right. Just metadata is what I needed. Thank you.